# Doctrine, Pagination, how many hits do I see?

Tags: doctrine-orm

there are 102 records in my database. If I set `->maxResult(100)`, I will have two pages, at one I can see `100` and at the second, I will see `2` hits.
Now, how to get those `2` or `100` result?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine's `setMaxResults($maxResults)` is like `LIMIT` in SQL.

To get second and other pages you should set `OFFSET` in SQL. Doctrine has `setFirstResult($offset)` for that.